Building Smartdiagram
I want to build a smart chart like this but I want to rotate the shapes to a vertical but that the text is still horizontal. I used the command shape border rotate=90 but it doesn't work.
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shapes.symbols}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    block/.style={signal, text width=2cm, minimum height=5cm, font=\tiny, draw=#1, fill=#1!30, signal pointer angle=120,shape border rotate=270}]
    \node[block=orange,signal from=above] (a) {\textbf{Experimentation}\\\textbf{Definition \& Supports}\\
    \begin{itemize}\item Experimentation suite \& benchmar methodology \item testbeds detailed analysis\end{itemize}};
    \node[block=green, right=0mm of a, signal from=west] at (0,-3) (b) {\textbf{Experimentation}\\\textbf{Definition \& Supports}\\
    \begin{itemize}\item Experimentation suite \& benchmar methodology \item testbeds detailed analysis\end{itemize}};  
    \node[block=blue, right=0mm of a, signal from=west] at (0,-7.1) (b) {\textbf{Experimentation}\\\textbf{Definition \& Supports}\\
    \begin{itemize}\item Experimentation suite \& benchmar methodology \item testbeds detailed analysis\end{itemize}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


You are missing \begin{document}

Instead of rotating the boarder, modify signal to=... and signal from=... to specify the direction the arrow should go:
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shapes.symbols}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    block/.style={signal, text width=5.5cm, draw=#1, fill=#1!30, signal pointer angle=120,signal to=south}]
    \node[block=orange,signal from=above] (a) {\textbf{Experimentation}\\\textbf{Definition \& Supports}\\
    \begin{itemize}\item Experimentation suite \& benchmar methodology \item testbeds detailed analysis\end{itemize}};
    \node[block=green,signal from=north,below=0mm of a] (b) {\textbf{Experimentation}\\\textbf{Definition \& Supports}\\
    \begin{itemize}\item Experimentation suite \& benchmar methodology \item testbeds detailed analysis\end{itemize}};  
    \node[block=blue, signal from=north,below=0mm of b]  {\textbf{Experimentation}\\\textbf{Definition \& Supports}\\
    \begin{itemize}\item Experimentation suite \& benchmar methodology \item testbeds detailed analysis\end{itemize}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



I am late to the party, to be sure. My approach would be to use TikZ chains. I would also delete the minimum height requirement and change text width to 3cm. Setting draw=gray gives, I think, a bit more definition. I've also removed extra space after \item by using enumitem, \setlist{nosep}.
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols,chains}

\tikzset{%
    mkchain/.style={start chain=going below,node distance=0pt,outer sep=0pt,
        every node/.style={on chain}},
    block/.style={signal, font=\tiny,text width=3cm, draw=gray, fill=#1!30,
        signal pointer angle=120,signal from=north,signal to=south}
}

\setlist{nosep}%% <<<---From enumitem--->>>

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[mkchain]
    \node[block=orange]
        {%
            \textbf{Experimentation}\\\textbf{Definition \& Supports}\\
            \begin{itemize}\item Experimentation suite \& benchmar methodology
                \item testbeds detailed analysis\end{itemize}
        };
    \node[block=green]
        {%
            \textbf{Experimentation}\\\textbf{Definition \& Supports}\\
            \begin{itemize}\item Experimentation suite \& benchmar methodology
                \item testbeds detailed analysis\end{itemize}%
        };  
    \node[block=blue]  
        {%
            \textbf{Experimentation}\\\textbf{Definition \& Supports}\\
            \begin{itemize}\item Experimentation suite \& benchmar methodology
                \item testbeds detailed analysis\end{itemize}%
        };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


